# Capture Alt, Ctrl or Shift in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, keyboard-events

Using Firefox I do not find a way to capture keyboard events with JavaScript  for Alt, Ctrl or Shift keys. It works on Chrome, Midori, SeaMonkey but not on Firefox.

Minimal reproducible example:

```js
window.onkeydown = event => console.log(event);
```

I push AltLeft key and on Chrome I get:

```
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "Alt", code: "AltLeft"...
```

On Midori 1.1.4:

```
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "Alt", code: "AltLeft"...
```

Basilisk (~ old Mozilla) 2021.02.06:

```
keydown Alt { target: <body>, key: "Alt", charCode: 0, keyCode: 18 }
```

SeaMonkey 2.53.6 (x64):

```
keydown Alt { target: <body>, key: "Alt", charCode: 0, keyCode: 18 }
```

Firefox 86.0 (x64):

... nothing. Same with Ctrl and Shift keys.

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1757]

Thanks in advance!

PS: Mentioning of IE doesn't even worth. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this in FireFox 86.0 and it works as expected.

```
keydown Shift { target: body.activity-stream, key: "Shift", charCode: 0, keyCode: 16 }

keydown Control { target: body.activity-stream, key: "Control", charCode: 0, keyCode: 17 }

keydown Alt { target: body.activity-stream, key: "Alt", charCode: 0, keyCode: 18 }
```

Please check your environment and provide further information to assist in debugging.

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1757]

Comment: Check it's not some plugin in your Firefox that is trying to prevent keylogging.

Comment: I've tried in SaveMode - no difference. Alt, Ctrl and Shift are not captured.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode

Comment: To confirm: does it log other keys, but just not shift, alt and ctrl?

Comment: Yes. It logs all keys except Alt, Ctrl and Shift. Only in Firefox.

Comment: Have you tried this on another computer and get same result? It has to be something local to your machine, or something else in your code that isn't shared here. Can you provide more context how this is intended to be used in your code? Is it inside an input/textarea?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exact same problem. After some googling I found the answer [Firefox not detecting Alt key on keydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69655210/firefox-not-detecting-alt-key-on-keydown)

Turns out that it was due to the fact that I have `about:config` `privacy.resistFingerprinting` set to true.  Turning it off solved the problem for me.