# Firefox not detecting Alt key on keydown

Tags: javascript, firefox, alt-key

Firefox on Windows 10 does not detect the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on `keydown` in conjunction with another key, but does detect the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. Chrome and Edge detect both as expected.

In Firefox, the following snippet shows that `event.shiftKey` is detected correctly, but `event.altKey` is never detected. In Chrome and Edge, `event.altKey` is detected correctly. (Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> triggers `keydown` in Chrome and Edge, but not in Firefox, which is why I said "in conjunction with another key.")

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head></head>

<body></body>

<script>
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    console.log("Alt: " + event.altKey);
    console.log("Shift: " + event.shiftKey);
  }, false);
</script>

</html>
```

[A question from 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014379/mozilla-firefox-version-69-0-alt-key-event-not-being-detected) reports the same problem in Firefox 69, but the solution was apparently that in Firefox, `&&` breaks something when used to detect if multiple keys including <kbd>Alt</kbd> are being pressed.

[A question from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952260/event-altkey-not-working-in-chrome-and-ie) reports the same problem in Chrome, with the answer being that pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> in Chrome enables the window menu, so the page loses focus and the `keypress` event is not called. Something similar could be going on in Firefox, because if the Menu Bar is enabled in Firefox, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> opens the first item (File) of the Menu Bar. However, the answer to that question says that "keydown" *does* work.

I'm using Firefox 93.0 on Windows 10. I tried opening Firefox in Troubleshoot Mode (as I have Firefox configured extensively) but the problem persisted.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: It appears that this was caused by `privacy.resistFingerprinting` in `about:config`.

Comment: Do you get different results with the left vs. right Alt keys? Does your keyboard have an `Alt Gr` key instead of an `Alt` key on one side?

Comment: @Dai No, neither of them are detected. I don't believe my keyboard has an `Alt Gr` key.

Comment: Interesting enough, with `privacy.resistFingerprinting` set to `true` I don't even get keyup and keydown event for Shift/Ctrl/Alt keys (I am running FF 105 ESR on Windows 10).